# Unity Geometry Shader Compiles forever

Tags: unity, shaders, geometry-shader, shaderlab

I am writing a shader to achieve a laser show effect [example](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Lasershow_Halifax_20070610.jpg).
For now I am just focusing on the lines. One line ist represented as one triangle.
When I save my shadercode, unity gets inactive and I can see in the task manager that the shader compiler has 30% cpu -> is compiling. But this takes forever, and when I restart unity, it isn't able to load the shader from the assets.
I found out that this doesn't happen when I comment the line:

```
const int TRI_STRIP[TAM] = tmpTriStrip;
```

Obviously I then get an error that TRI_STRIP is undefined, but the shadercompiler did its work and Unity is still running.
Then I put the line back into the code and the above desribed behaviour appears.
Thanks for any tipps and advices.

Here is the complete geometryshader code:

```
    void myGeometryShader(point gIn vert[1], inout TriangleStream<v2f> triStream)
{
    float f = _PointSize / 20.0f * sin(_Time * _Speed); //half size

    float4 vctmp[TAM];

    int i;
    float y;
    for (i = 0; i < TAM; i += 3) {

        y = sin(_Time * _Speed + _SinValue) * _MovHeight + _HeightOffset;
        vctmp[i] = float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        vctmp[i + 1] = float4(_Distance, y, i / _MarginFactor - _EndWidth / 2.0f, 0.0f);
        vctmp[i + 2] = float4(_Distance, y, i / _MarginFactor + _EndWidth / 2.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    const float4 vc[TAM] = vctmp;


    float2 UV1tmp[TAM];
    for (i = 0; i < TAM; i += 3) {
        UV1tmp[i] = float2(0.0f, 0.0f);
        UV1tmp[i + 1] = float2(1.0f, 0.0f);
        UV1tmp[i + 2] = float2(1.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    const float2 UV1[TAM] = UV1tmp;

    int tmpTriStrip[TAM];

    for (i = 0; i < TAM; i++) {
        tmpTriStrip[i] = 1;
    }

    const int TRI_STRIP[TAM] = tmpTriStrip;

    v2f v[TAM];


    // Assign new vertices positions 
    for (i = 0; i < TAM; i++) { v[i].pos = vert[0].pos + vc[i]; v[i].col = vert[0].col; }

    // Assign UV values
    for (i = 0; i < TAM; i++) v[i].uv_MainTex = TRANSFORM_TEX(UV1[i],_MainTex);

    // Position in view space
    for (i = 0; i < TAM; i++) { v[i].pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v[i].pos); }

    // Build the cube tile by submitting triangle strip vertices
    for (i = 0; i < TAM / 3; i++)
    {
        triStream.Append(v[TRI_STRIP[i * 3 + 0]]);
        triStream.Append(v[TRI_STRIP[i * 3 + 1]]);
        triStream.Append(v[TRI_STRIP[i * 3 + 2]]);

        triStream.RestartStrip();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The looks like a compiler bug.

But in any case:

- You don't need the copy into a const array, just use the non-const one.
- You don't need those large arrays, from what I see everything in the shader can be done in a single `for (i = 0; i < TAM; i += 3)` loop with small arrays of 3.

That should work around the compiler bug and probably make the shader faster.

Comment: Thanks. For verts and uvs I can use normal arrays, but for the triangleStrip it has to be constant. Why are smaller arrays sufficient?

Comment: The array is just filled with 1s: ` int tmpTriStrip[TAM];

    for (i = 0; i < TAM; i++) {
        tmpTriStrip[i] = 1;
    }

    const int TRI_STRIP[TAM] = tmpTriStrip;`

Comment: And you can calculate the values 3 at a time in 1 loop instead of calculating an entire array and then using it in a different loop.

Comment: Ahh ok now i see, thanks. I will definitly do that.